# Regular expression for all words not containing 222

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I need to find a regular expression for the language of all words over $\{0,1,2,3\}$ which do not contain $222$ as a substring.

Comment: What do you mean by a "substring"? Does it have to be consecutive?

Comment: This is a problem dump. What effort have you made to solve this exercise on your own? Can you solve it with 222 replaced by 2? With 222 replaced by 22?